# Create and Deploy a DACPAC file with Data

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

In SSMS 2014 I created a DACPAC file using Tasks > Extract Data-Tier Application.

I then Deployed the file to an Azure SQL Database. The scheme it deployed but all the tables are empty with no data.

How can I export the data? I though that SQL Server 2014 DACPAC file already included the data ...

Answer (score 1):

To move a database to Azure SQL you need to extract a BACPAC file which contains the data as well as schema. The DACPAC file does not contain the data.

Go to
Tasks > Export Data-Tier Application and you will get the file required.

**Look here for more details   :**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/export-a-data-tier-application

Comment: Yes, I did that and it worked but how to upgrade future versions of the database? Isn't BACPAC only for the first version since it must create the database?

Comment: DACPAC allows you to upgrade the schema of an existing database with a new version from another source, but I don't believe it allows for importing of new data.

Answer (score 1):

You can include data from specific tables or from all tables in a DACPAC by using the [SqlPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-extract?view=sql-server-ver15#properties-specific-to-the-extract-action) tool.

```
SqlPackage.exe /a:Extract /p:ExtractAllTableData=true /SourceServerName:localhost /SourceDatabaseName:somedb /TargetFile:db.dacpac
```

```
SqlPackage.exe /a:Extract /p:TableData=dbo.SomeTable /p:TableData=dbo.SomeOtherTable /SourceServerName:localhost /SourceDatabaseName:somedb /TargetFile:db.dacpac
```